# What is reason to get python model conversion error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, nosetests

> ModelConversionError: {'subscriber': {'contacts': [u'Please use a mapping for this field or Contacts instance instead of list.']}

I am getting `ModelConversionError` like above. What I have to do to correct those error and reason for getting that?

```
class Contacts(Model):
    communication_number2 = StringType(min_length=1, max_length=50)
    communication_type2 = StringType(min_length=1, max_length=50)

class Subscriber(Member):
    master_policy_number = StringType()
    address = ModelType(Address)
    contacts = ModelType(Contacts)
```

Comment: Can you give more info? Your code, the full stack trace? Are you using any flask extensions? Am I right in thinking you're using `flask-appengine-template`?

Comment: Add it to the question is best :)